# how to redirect specify url in action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

My Default Route Config is

```
routes.MapRoute("Login", "{controller}/{action}", new { controller = "Customer", action = "Login" });
```

Now I want to redirect to WorkOrder/HomePage/{PageName} in

```
public ActionResult Submit(string commandName, WorkOrderModel addModel)
   {
     //How Can I redirect to WorkOrder/HomePage/{PageName}
     //Return View()
   }
```

How Can I Do?

Answer (score -1):

I hope you can change the returning type. Try this:

```
    public RedirectResult Redirect()
    {
        return RedirectPermanent($"/WorkOrder/HomePage/{PageName}");
    }
```